# Tag Redux: `package`, `package-install`, and `package-designer` should we simplify?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

So, in reading the question: [Package Designer shows blank modal window when clicking "Generate ZIP"](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/package-designer-shows-blank-modal-window-when-clicking-generate-zip)

We have three tags in use:

1. [package](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package)
2. [package-install](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-install)
3. [package-designer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-designer)

Our current strategy has been to label tags after products of Sitecore. For example [exm](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exm), [list-manager](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-manager), [content-editor](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-editor), [experience-editor](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experience-editor), to name a few.

If we were to carry this strategy across to [package-designer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-designer) and [install-wizard](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/install-wizard) I think that makes a lot of sense.

To me, [package](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package) is too broad of a tag, and [package-install](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-install) makes me question "if it's on creation" (depending on the question).

So, I'll pose it to the community, what do you think makes the most sense here with these tags?

Comment: `package` has been renamed to `packages`, `package-install` has been made a synonym of `packages`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something to consider about package tags—we need to take into account that there are (module) packages and update packages. They have different formats, different UIs/tooling and different usage patterns.

Here's a list of all package tags we have right now:

- [package](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package)
- [update-packages](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update-packages)
- [package-install](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-install)
- [package-designer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-designer)

There are currently 8 [package-install](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-install) questions and only one [package-designer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-designer) question. Honestly, I don't believe there will be many questions related to creating packages. Most will be related to package installation problems. So I don't think [package-install](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-install), [package-installation](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-installation) or [install-wizard](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/install-wizard) make sense—first, they are ambiguous between package types. Second, I doubt anyone will search based on any of these tags.

I can imagine people searching for questions tagged by [package-designer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-designer), since that's the module that creates packages, and it does have its own tricks and issues.

### Proposal

We should concentrate on splitting all package-related questions into [packages](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages) and [update-packages](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update-packages).
<sup>(Note that we should use the [plural form of "packages"](https://sitecore.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164) instead of "package".)</sup>

We should be left with just two major tags in the end:

- [packages](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages) (synonym: [package](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package))
- [update-packages](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update-packages)

I propose that we also keep [package-designer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-designer)—it will sometimes be used together with [packages](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages). Similarly to how [tds](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tds) will be used for package creation questions of [update-packages](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update-packages).

Comment: As discussed, I second this. Let's give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, something needs to be done. [package](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package) is not a tag I can envision someone would search by or set up an alert for.

I guess package related problems would fall under one of two categories. [package-installation](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-installation) and [package-creation](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-creation).  I need to look a little bit closer on how people have been using this tag though.

**EDIT**

Ok I've looked. So. One one hand, I agree, if we follow through on the principle, that the general Sitecore application/product should be in the tag, [package-designer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-designer) and [installation-wizard](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installation-wizard) would be appropriate.

I hesitate on the last one however, I don't think most people would notice it is there. They would start typing `package` and tag auto completion would not indicate it is there. That's why I would prefer [package-installation](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-installation) as the second tag. We can then set up [installation-wizard](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installation-wizard) as an alias for that tag.

That would be my recommentaion.

TL;DR

We go with [package-designer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-designer) and [package-installation](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-installation). And we create [installation-wizard](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installation-wizard) as an alias for [package-installation](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-installation)