# Tag rename request: package –> packages

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Similar tag names are commonly pluralized. To be consistent, please rename [package](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package) to [packages](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages).

Comment: Done - I created a tag synonym and performed a tag merge.